# How can I add a fragment to a ViewPager? addView crashes my app

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using the default Swipe Tab Fragment code that Android starts with when you start a new Android application. I've figured out how to modify my data and use the tabs, but I haven't figured out how to add a simple fragment to what's already there. I wanted to add a infobar on the top of the tabs or right below them. I'm sure it's simple, I just can't figure out how lol. I learn by examples.

I've tried adding a view to viewpager, but my app is crashing, and I believe I'm totally doing it wrong.

In my MainActivity:
...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    SubBarFragment infobar = new SubBarFragment();
    mViewPager.addView(infobar.getView());      
.....[extra code for menus and things]

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
....[code to show specific tabs and return the tab's fragment]
```

infobarfragment.java

```
public class InfobarFragment extends Fragment {

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infobar, container, false);
        return view;
      }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

infobar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_wifi" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statusText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Wifi Status Information" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you have a adapter for the ViewPager, use the method getItem / instanciateItem (depends on what you are using: fragments or simple views). these method gives the viewpager object all needed views.

Comment: can you return more than one fragment in the adapter? I've figured how to add fragment using Santhosh's help, but it just treats it as another 'page' I can swipe through. I want it to be persistant no matter what page I'm on. I had wanted it to be above the tabs, but I don't think that's possible. So having it below tabs is fine for now I guess. Thoughts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can follow this approach:

just Use fragments for each view in a pager.

write the below code in `onCreate()` method of the `FragmentActivity`.

```
List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

//for each fragment you want to add to the pager
Bundle page = new Bundle();
page.putString("url", url);
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,MyFragment.class.getName(),page));

//after adding all the fragments write the below lines

this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

mPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
```

> **A sample fragment definition:**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {


public static MyFragment newInstance(String imageUrl) {

final MyFragment mf = new MyFragment ();

    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("somedata", "somedata");
    mf.setArguments(args);

    return mf;
}

public MyFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String data = getArguments().getString("somedata");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate and locate the main ImageView
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_view, container, false);
    //... 
    return v;
}
```

> **FragmentPagerAdapter**

```
public class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public static int pos = 0;

private List<Fragment> myFragments;

public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> myFrags) {
    super(fm);
    myFragments = myFrags;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return myFragments.get(position);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return myFragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    setPos(position);

    String PageTitle = "";

    switch(pos)
    {
        case 0:
                PageTitle = "page 1";
                break;
        case 1:
                PageTitle = "page 2";
                break;
        case 2:
                PageTitle = "page 3";
                break;
        case 3:
                PageTitle = "page 4";
                break;
        case 4:
                PageTitle = "page 5";
                break;
        case 5: 
                PageTitle = "page 6";
                break;
        case 6:
                PageTitle = "page 7";
                break;
    }
    return PageTitle;
}

public static int getPos() {
    return pos;
}

 public static void setPos(int pos) {
    MyFragmentAdapter.pos = pos;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Santhosh. This helps me understand how to add a fragment to my current adapter much easier! I can get a fragment added, but it just treats my fragment that I add like another page that I can swipe through. If I swipe to a different tab, I want my 'statusbar' fragment that I added to stay on the top or bottom no matter what page I swipe to. In essence, the statusbar is like a sub-actionbar. Just lets me user know the status of whats going on.

Do I need to re-work my strategy?

Comment: The fragments are added to the view Pager. I think you can create a layout(linearlayout[vertical]) for the fragment activity having <statusbar> fragment_container at the top and then viewpager below it.