# ViewPager with Fragment having listview

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am new to Android and running into a problem. I am having one FragmentActivity and having viewpager with one fragment (Internal fragment) - I have one list view in that internal fragment and on click of this list i want to show another fragment replacing this view pager.

Please don't mark this as duplicate. I have searched a lot of question but didn't found this.

FYI - Viewpager i am using with action bar.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: check this post for some idea. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16232501/1567588

Comment: @Santhosh I have show another fragment on click of listview inside fragment, please suggest the way

Comment: you have one main fragmentActivity that has viewpager, then that viewpager has item you call as internal fragment. Now on click of that listview item you want to replace that viewpager? Correct me if I'm wrong. So is it like your mainActivity containing viewpager is a God Activity? and you want to replace that onclick of listitem?

Comment: you are correct @MOSO, I want to replace that fragment with my New fragment and have to hide Action bar swipeable tabs as well. I will be like new screen.

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing? Any code ?